# gulp-sass. Как отменить вставку строки @charset "UTF-8"?

Tags: css, gulp, gulp-sass

При компиляции "[style].scss" gulp-sass автоматом вставляет первой строкой
@charset "UTF-8"

Как можно этого избежать, есть ли какая-либо опция?

```js
return gulp.src( paths.src.css )
    // ...
    .pipe( sass().on( 'error', sass.logError ) )
    // ...
    .pipe( gulp.dest( paths.dest.css ) );
```

На выходе в файле получаю:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
@font-face { /* ... */ }
```

а надо без UTF-8:

```
@font-face { /* ... */ }
```

Проблема: @charset "UTF-8" можно вставить только в первой строке файла css,
но выходной файл необходимо собирать на сервере из нескольких, что-то типа:

```
cache = writeCache("file_1.css" . "file_2.css" . [...]);
header("Content-Type: text/css;charset=UTF-8");
echo cache["gz"];
```

Comment: https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/2288 говорят нельзя, тк опирались на спецификацию css. Так что на беке вырезайте эту строку

Comment: Спасибо, странно что не включили такую опцию, добавил к плагинам ***gulp-replace***

Answer (score 2):

По наводке [Artem Gorlachev](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/219254/artem-gorlachev) оказалось что разработчики не включили эту опцию.

Пришлось добавить:

```
// npm install --save-dev gulp-replace
const replace = require( 'gulp-replace' );
return gulp.src( paths.src.css )
    // ...
    .pipe( sass().on( 'error', sass.logError ) )
    .pipe( replace( /^[ \t]*\@charset[ \t]+\"UTF\-8\"[ \t]*;/gmi, '' ) )
    .pipe( gulp.dest( paths.dest.css ) );
```

На выходе получаем без всяких ***charset-ов***!